# jquery validator hide div on submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I've got a validator that hides the submit buttons (and shows a please wait message) after user hits submit.

However it's also doing it when a date field validates.

Is it possible to only hide and show the divs when the command comes from one of the submit buttons, but not when the dates validate on change?

Comment: Please can you post code to help us resolve the issue. It's a bit hard to imagine - hence @RobertRozas's comment.

Comment: You've been around long enough to know what a good question is..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible , and it's just basics. More things are possible
See jQuery API - http://api.jquery.com/

Sample:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#div1").hide();
 $("#div2").hide();
  $("#button1").click(function(){
    $("#div1").hide();
    $("#div2").show();
  });
  $("#button2").click(function(){
     $("#div2").hide();
    $("#div1").show();
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="div1">this is div1</div>
<div id="div2">this is div2</div>
<button id="button1">button1</button>
<button id="button2">button2</button>
</body>
</html>
```

or you can assign a common **class** to the common `<div>` you want to hide or show and do  `$(".yourclassname").hide();`  or `$(".yourclassname").show();`

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to only hide and show the divs when the command comes from one of the submit buttons, but not when the dates validate on change?

Yes.